# How to sort a content of a text file using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I am interested how to know how to sort a content of a file using shell scripting.

Here is an example:

```
fap0089-josh.baker
fap00233-adrian.edwards
fap00293-bob.boyle
fap00293-bob.jones
fap002-brian.lopez
fap00293-colby.morris
fap00293-cole.mitchell
psf0354-SKOWALSKI
psf0354-SLEE
psf0382-SLOWE
psf0391-SNOMURA
psf0354-SPATEL
psf0364-SRICHARDS
psf0354-SSEIBERT
psf0354-SSIRAH
bsi0004-STRAN
bsi0894-STURBIC
unit054-SUNDERWOOD
```

Considering the data above (this is a small set, I have more than 5.5 records), I would like to sort it like this:

1. Number of entries starting with fap,psf,bsi,unit etc...
2. The total number of environments for each type, i.e: each numeric after the word, 0004,0382,054 etc are environments. e.g: psf has 4 unique environments.
3. The sum total

Comment: "Number of entries starting with fap,psf,bsi,unit etc" meaning the number of lines by each prefix type? "total number of environments for each type" the numbers from the first part broken down by sub-type as well? "The sum total" of what? Do you mean "sorting" or do you mean "analyzing"/"counting"? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Given this input, what output are you expecting to see?

Comment: Do you want to *sort* the file, or are you looking to simply get the totals you want. Would you consider an `awk` solution to your problem? `awk` is really its own programming language, but it's such an old part of Unix that many people consider using `awk` as a _shell solution_.

Comment: Hi @DavidW.
Here is the original file : http://www.filedropper.com/all-dss-accounts
There are 565075 entries in this file.
Majority entries are of the format : <app><env>-<user>
e.g for app is fap,sbl,unit,jde etc
e.g for env is a numeric (maybe 3 digit or 4 digit or 5 digit)
I want the results to have the following:
a) Total number of entries in the file.
b) App name & the number (count) of entries
c) App name & the number (count) of unique env.

The result needs to be in a tabular format and needs to be stored in a .txt file as well as sent to an email.

Comment: @EtanReisner
Here is the original file : filedropper.com/all-dss-accounts There are 565075 entries in this file. Majority entries are of the format : <app><env>-<user> e.g for app is fap,sbl,unit,jde etc e.g for env is a numeric (maybe 3 digit or 4 digit or 5 digit) 
I want the results to have the following: 
a) Total number of entries in the file. 
b) App name & the number (count) of entries c) App name & the number (count) of unique env. The result needs to be in a tabular format and needs to be stored in a .txt file as well as sent to an email.

Comment: @Karthik - Maybe the best way is to imagine that the input you gave us is the file, and show us exactly what you want the output to be. You said _sort_, but your description seems to ask for just a few figures. Then, you said this should be a *table*. Just show what the final output should look like.

Comment: @DavidW. Here is the sample of the required output - http://www.filedropper.com/sample

Comment: @Karthik Just put the example output in your program. I'm not signing up just to download your program.

Comment: @DavidW.
Original file which needs to be sorted : http://wikisend.com/download/264164/all-dss-accounts.txt
Expected Output :
http://wikisend.com/download/302174/sample.txt

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Schwarzian transform to sort by 1) leading letters, then 2) digits

```
sed -r 's/^([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)/\1 \2 /' filename | 
sort -t ' ' -k 1,1 -k 2,2n | 
sed 's/ //; s/ //'
```

output:

```
bsi0004-STRAN
bsi0894-STURBIC
fap002-brian.lopez
fap0089-josh.baker
fap00233-adrian.edwards
fap00293-bob.boyle
fap00293-bob.jones
fap00293-colby.morris
fap00293-cole.mitchell
psf0354-SKOWALSKI
psf0354-SLEE
psf0354-SPATEL
psf0354-SSEIBERT
psf0354-SSIRAH
psf0364-SRICHARDS
psf0382-SLOWE
psf0391-SNOMURA
unit054-SUNDERWOOD
```

To generate the metrics you mention, I'd use perl:

```
perl -nE '
    /^([[:alpha:]]+)(\d+)/ or next;
    $count{$1}++;
    $nenv{$1}{$2}=1;
    $total+=$2
} 
END {
    say "Counts:";
    say "$_ => $count{$_}" for sort keys %count;
    say "Number of environments";
    say "$_ => ", scalar keys %{$nenv{$_}} for sort keys %nenv;
    say "Total = $total";
' filename
```

```
Counts:
bsi => 2
fap => 7
psf => 8
unit => 1
Number of environments
bsi => 2
fap => 4
psf => 4
unit => 1
Total = 5355
```

Without using perl, it's less efficient because you have to read the file multiple times.

```
echo Counts:
sed 's/[0-9].*//' filename | sort | uniq -c 
echo Number of environments:
sed -r 's/^([a-z]+)([0-9]*).*/\1 \2/' filename | sort -u | cut -d" " -f1 | uniq -c
echo Total:
{ printf "%d+" $(sed -r 's/^[a-z0]+([0-9]*).*/\1/' filename); echo 0; } | bc
```

```
Counts:
      2 bsi
      7 fap
      8 psf
      1 unit
Number of environments:
      2 bsi
      4 fap
      4 psf
      1 unit
Total:
5355
```

Comment: I am bad at perl. Does this perl script work when its put into a shell file under the shell script?
Can this be implemented in pure unix code?

Comment: There's no such thing as "pure unix code". Shell scripts are merely commands executed in some order, and perl is a command like grep or sed. Nevertheless, I've added a perl-free version

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn. I am using this script to run this file. It throws up error.
File : http://www.filedropper.com/all-dss-accounts
This file contains 565075 records which needs to be sorted.

Comment: Moreover, Instead of the number of environments, I need the count of only the unique environments. For e.g: 'fap' has got total of 7 environments but the number of unique environments is 4 (cos 00293 is repeated in 4 entries.

Comment: Here is the original file : filedropper.com/all-dss-accounts There are 565075 entries in this file. Majority entries are of the format : <app><env>-<user> e.g for app is fap,sbl,unit,jde etc e.g for env is a numeric (maybe 3 digit or 4 digit or 5 digit) I want the results to have the following: a) Total number of entries in the file. b) App name & the number (count) of entries c) App name & the number (count) of unique env. The result needs to be in a tabular format and needs to be stored in a .txt file as well as sent to an email.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You did not update your question when I asked you to show your expected output. Don't expect us, who are volunteering our time to help you, to chase you again and again for requirements.

Comment: Sorry glenn. I need your help. I did not happen to see the question. I'm new to this forum. Please help me!

Comment: Hey glenn, here is a sample of how the end report should look like. Sample - http://www.filedropper.com/sample

Comment: This is brilliant, useful, and should be considered as a good sed exercise! Love it.